# handle errors in Python ArgumentParser

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, argparse

I want to manually handle the situation where `parse_args()` throws an error in case of a unknown value for an argument. For example:
If I have the following python file called `script.py`:

```
argp = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='example')
argp.add_argument('--compiler', choices=['default', 'clang3.4', 'clang3.5'])
args = argp.parse_args()
```

and I run the script with the following args `python script.py --compiler=foo` it throws the following error:

```
error: argument --compiler: invalid choice: 'foo' (choose from 'default', 'clang3.4', 'clang3.5')
SystemExit: 2
```

What do I need to do in order to handle this behaviour myself instead of the script quitting itself? One idea is to subclass `argparse.ArgumentParser` and override `parse_args()` or just monkey patch the method but I was wondering if there's a better way that does not require overriding the standard library behaviour?

Comment: How do you want to handle a different choice from your choice list?

Comment: @M.Klugerford doesn't matter, but to simplify, if a certain flag is passed along with a compiler value that is not in the choices list, I want to say that the scrip should be run assuming `clang3.4` as the argument.

Comment: What about creating a custom [action](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#action-classes)?

Comment: @FamousJameous This looks promising. Will look into it and update here. Do you have a good example for reference?

Comment: @Siddharth, Full disclosure, I have never written a custom action in `argparse`. I have done similar things in `optparse`, just never `argparse`. There is a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632354/python-argparse-custom-actions-with-additional-arguments-passed that might help.

Comment: @FamousJameous Do you suggest optparse over argparse? If so, what are the arguments?

Comment: Nvm, just found out it's deprecated. There's no point to it since this script needs to run on 3.4, 3.5, 3.6 as well as PyPy.

Comment: `optparse` won't disappear.  New development in `argparse` is encouraged, but not required.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `__call__` method from a custom Action class gets called after the verification of choices so it does no help the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point to defining choices is to make the parser complain about values that are not in the list.  But there are some alternatives:

- omit choices (include them in the help text if you want), and do your own testing after parsing. `argparse` doesn't have to do everything for you.  It's main purpose is to figure out what your user wants.
- redefine the `parser.error` method (via subclassing is best) to redirect the error from `sys.exit`.  But you'll have to parse the error message to distinguish between this error and other ones that the parser might raise.
- define a `type` function that checks for choices, and makes the default substitution.

The parsing of the '--compiler' option goes something like this:

- grab the string argument after the `--compiler` flag
- pass it through the `type` function.  Default is `lambda x:x`.  `int` converts it to integer, etc.  Raise `ValueError` is value is bad.
- check the returned value against the `choices` list (if any)
- use the `action` to add the value to the Namespace (default simply stores it).

Error in any of these steps produces an `ArgumentError` which is trapped by the `parser.error` method and passed to a `parser.exit` method.

Since the `store_action` occurs after `type` and `choices` checking, a custom action won't bypass their errors.

Here's a possible `type` solution (not tested)

```
def compile_choices(astr):
   if astr in ['default', 'clang3.4', 'clang3.5']:
       return astr
   else:
       return 'default'
   # could raise ValueError('bad value') if there are some strings you don't like

argp.add_argument('--compiler', type=compile_choices)
```

=================

If `compile_choices` takes other arguments, such as the list of choices or the default, you'll need to wrap in some why that defines those values before parsing.

An example accepting a binary string representation:

```
parser.add_argument('--binary', type=lambda x: int(x, base=2),
    help='integer in binary format', default='1010')
```

or

```
parser.add_argument('--binary', type=functools.partial(int, base=2), default='1010')
```

Comment: What if I want to pass another argument to compile_choices along with the compiler value?

Comment: Use `lambda` or `partial` or a wrapper function to provide those arguments before giving it to the parser.  I added an example.